# How to open a custom dropdown inside the quill editor?

Tags: quill

I have created a custom dropdown in the toolbar in quill editor in a pure JavaScript project. How can I display the same dropdown inside the editor on clicking "#"?

I tried to track the key press like this:

quill.keyboard.addBinding({
key: 219, // code for # symbol
shiftKey: false,
handler: function(range, context) {
console.log('Display Dropdown');
}
});

To open the dropdown inside the editor as a suggestion.